# How to add a new object to an interface table?

Tags: laravel

I am writing an lms. I have a product model, an attribute model, and a productAttribute interface table.
All attributes can be seen on the product creation page, and when filled, they are stored in the interface table.
But on the product editing page, the attributes added after creating the product cannot be filled because we read the attributes from the interface table.

Now I want to do something so that when I create a new attribute, it is added to the interface table for all products with an empty value to fill in the edit page if needed.
I added this code inside the store method in attributeController:

```
$attributes=Attribute::create([
    'name' => $request->name
]);

$product = Product::all();
$productAttributeController = new ProductAttributeController();
$productAttributeController->store($attributes, $product);
```

And inside the ProductAttributeController, I receive and store the values like this:

```
public function store($attributes, $product)
{
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
        ProductAttribute::create([
            'product_id' => $product->id,
            'attribute_id' => $key,
            'value' => $value,
        ]);        
    }    
}
```

### I used from $key because when I create a product, I get an array here
it gives this error when I make an Attribute:
((Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance))
If possible, please guide me on how to send the new feature so that it doesn't give an error.

I solved it with this code:

```
$products = Product::all();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
          ProductAttribute::create([
        'product_id' => $product->id, 
        'attribute_id' => $attribute->id
        ]);}
```

thank you @win

Comment: You mean when you add a new field with a migration ? in that case you can use >default function when creating the field to define a default value for that field

Comment: I want to create a row in the interface table (AttributeProduct) for all products, when I create an object from the attribute model.
@Lk77

Comment: `$product = Product::all()` resulting multiple products in collection ... this is why you get error id  does not exist ... if you want to get only one, use `Product::query()->first()` or better yet `Product::where('field', $id)->first()`

Comment: Attribute::create() will only create a single $attribute, foreach will resulting error

Comment: @Win
thank you very much! it fixed with this code:
$products = Product::all();
        foreach ($products as $product) {
          ProductAttribute::create([
        'product_id' => $product->id, 
        'attribute_id' => $attribute->id
        ]);}

Comment: @MRCoder Please don't add the answer to your question or in the comments. There is an answer section below. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75246498/edit), remove the answer, and post it below.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the correct table connection.

```
   products > product_attributes > attributes
```

With products has id and name.
product_attributes has product_id and attribute_id.
and attributes has id and name

So a single `product` can have multiple `attribute` and store this data inside a pivot table called `product_attributes`.
A many-to-many relationship

I'm guessing you already create 3 models for all 3 tables:
Product, ProductAttribute and Attribute.

I'll try to describe below what you need to do to add Attribute to a Product through ProductAttribute.

Add relation into your model Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
   ....
   ....

   public function product_attributes()
   {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(Attribute::class, ProductAttribute::class);
   }
}
```

Lets state inside your model Attribute a relation to Product

```
class Attribute extends Model
{
   ....
   ....

   public function product()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->using(ProductAttribute::class);
   }
}
```

Now we can use this relationship to add attribute into product

```
$attribute = Attribute::create([
            'name' => $request->name
        ]);

// re-retrieve the instance to get all of the fields in the table ie. id
$attribute = $attribute->fresh();

$product = Product::where('id', $id)->first();

// you can use this way to add new Product-Attribute relation
ProductAttribute::create([
  'product_id' => $product->id, 
  'attribute_id' => $attribute->id
]);

// OR using Laravel magic function ->attach()
$product->product_attributes()->attach($attribute->id);
```

Here is some documentation for you to read further:

- [eloquent tables with many to many relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)
- [how to add and update many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

---

By the way, I'm not really certain yet why you access the controller in this way ?

```
$productAttributeController = new ProductAttributeController();
```

And where did you call it ? 
Why not using it properly with browser `routes/web.php` or API
`routes/api.php` ?